# Should the "remote" tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I suspect that the [remote](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote) tag was created in error when someone (maybe me) tried to add the [remote-sensing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-sensing) tag to a question.  As there is no way to flag this tag for moderators outside of GISmeta, should this tag be removed?  I would not normally care, although in this case it becomes the default tag when trying to add the [remote-sensing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-sensing) tag.  Additionally, there are no questions associated with this tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having no questions associated with this tag means that the system should clean it up within 24 hours (I think) and the graphic below suggests that this has already happened:

[image]

If you are worried about it coming back, or about the existence of any other undesirable tags, then there are bigger sticks that can be used to deal with them such as burnination and blacklisting.  For more information on those options see  [What does it mean to "burninate" a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag)

I think there may be a case to request blacklisting of the [remote](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote) tag.